Steam Open Id ASP.NET Core cookie not found error
I am developing a Web API application, I want to enable authorization via steam.
After logging in on the site, I get an error:

statusCode: 500
An error was encountered while handling the remote login

In the logs, I see:

warn: ASPnet.Security.OpenID.Steam.SteamAuthenticationHandler[15] '.AspNetCore.Correlation.leZeMwx_j1MAdBSrk-iCVNq4oHlg7Y7WDuuGT4PkG-s' cookie not found.
info: AspNet.Security.OpenId.Steam.SteamAuthenticationHandler[4]
Error from RemoteAuthentication: The authentication response was rejected because the anti-forgery token was invalid..

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
    {
        opt.TokenValidationParameters = new()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtOpt!.SecretKey))
        };

        opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                context.Token = context.Request.Cookies[jwtOpt.CookieAccessKey];

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    })
    .AddSteam(options =>
    {
        options.ApplicationKey = "MyApiKey";
        options.CallbackPath = "/User/Verify";
    });

[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task SignInSteam()
{
    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(SteamAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Verify)),
        });
}

I get the url of the steam site and send it to the client application, where I open the steam in a new tab. Maybe I'm doing something wrong (I didn't find a normal guide for the rest asp steam auth).
